# Trouble with rectifying a pulse with a diode

Tags: diodes, rectifier

I'm trying to obtain a pulse from a square-wave of a function generator.
I thought it is an easy straightforward thing.
So in this case the square-wave is +5V to -5V. I use a 1N4001 diode and a 220 Ohm series resistor.

As you see in the below simulation output will go to a comparator's input. Green plot is the output voltage (Out):

[image]
(V1 represents the function generator)

But I'm having those negative spikes during falling edges both in scope and in simulation.

My questions are:

1-) How can I prevent those negative spikes? I need around zero volt during OFF time of the pulse without such spikes. Why do these spikes occur?

2-) Is 220 Ohm okay or better to use 50 Ohm? (Im asking because at the output of the function generator it is written 50 Ohm)

Comment: Have you tried different diodes? Your frequency isn't that high but 4001 isn't very fast either.

Comment: You might want to try familiarizing with how diodes work in real life, what parameters matter and what those are for the specific diode you have at hand

Comment: If all you're trying to do is get a positive pulse from a function generator, surely you could just adjust the function generator's offset knob such that its square wave output is centered at half of the output amplitude (2.5V for a 5V pulse)?

Comment: how about adding a small (470pF or something like that) cap to smoothen the edge off your signal. Btw. how you got LTSpice to show these negative spikes. For fun I tried your model and I dont get them to show up.

Comment: @KarlKarlsom the diode is: .model 1N4001 D(Is=14.11n N=1.984 Rs=33.89m Ikf=94.81 Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Cjo=25.89p M=.44 Vj=.3245 Fc=.5 Bv=75 Ibv=10u Tt=5.7u Iave=1 Vpk=50 mfg=GI type=silicon)

Comment: @KarlKarlsom Use a square wave with 10kHz as input

Comment: the negative spikes look like the expected behavior of an inductor, when current is suddenly interrupted. Indeed, this is how "boost regulators" work. You can't tell from the schematic, but is it possible your wiring is sufficiently long to have a noticeable inductive affect? You said the input was a square wave, and if its edges are sharp enough, it wouldn't take much inductance to produce this effect. You might need to add a simple low pass RC filter between the generator and the diode.

Comment: @Randy How do u explain that inductive effect in simulation? I changed to Schottky it worked better.

Comment: @user16307 - my bad if its a simulation. I thought it was cut/pasted from a PC based scope display. If its a simulation, I'd want to confirm on a real scope before anything else. It could be that in REALITY, those negative pulses never make it into the real world. After all, a "simulated" square wave input could certainly have impossible transition speeds, right?

Comment: @Randy This is one of the lines from my question: "But I'm having those negative spikes during falling edges both in scope and in simulation" I do have spikes both on scope i.e real life in practice; and in LTspice simulation as well. I think Olin Lathrop's point on recovery time was an issue above particular frequencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look up the *reverse recovery time* in the diode datasheet.  The 1N400x series sssslllllooooowwwww.  These are meant for 50/60 Hz power rectification, not for fast signals.

Either use a fast signal diode like the 1N4148, or a Schottky.  Due to the physics of Schottky diodes, their reverse recovery time is very fast.  It can often be considered 0 in ordinary applications.  The general downsides to Schottky diodes is that they aren't available for high reverse voltages, and they have much higher reverse leakage than full silicon diodes, especially at high temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a better understanding of what is happening if you show the generator's output. I suspect that what is happening is that stray capacitance on the output is being charged during the conduction phase and is discharging via the resistor in the non conducting phase. Altering the resistors value will change the shape of the negative pulse, increasing its value will widen the pulse shape while decreasing it will make it narrower. Remember that you are working with a voltage range of _5 to +5 not 0 to +5